# Partitions - What can I format?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

Im trying to completely format/empty my 1tb HDD so I can do a 100% fresh Install of Windows 10.

When I started installing Windows it gave me the option to choose my partition but there was many Partitions - I looked at the Total Size and it had "930~mb" so I chose that one and clicked Format and it jumped from 530mb~ free space to 921mb~

It had other partitions like "Recovery" and such, Are these OK to format and is there anything else I should format - I want my HDD to be as if I just bought it.

Comment: You should not delete the rest of your partitions while not needed, if you have a problem, it makes it easier to solve problems

Answer (score 0):

I can actually format everything :)

I found out that if you run CMD in the F2/F8/DEL menu when booting up your PC - You can type `diskpart` > `disk list` > `select disk {x}` > `clean` and then it will completely clean and fully format the HDD - Just make sure you choose the right one. Then go ahead and install Windows :)

Only do this if you have all your files backed up somewhere else and that you want to re-install windows completely.

Doing this removed 430gb of Cache'd files findable with stuff like Mini Partition Manager etc.

Comment: No need to leave setup by the way. Just use Shift+F10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Shift+f10

And you can follow this steps:

---

### DISC PART

list disk

select disk for example: 1

clean

create partition primary

active

format fs=fat32(can be ntfs) labe="Some_think" quick

assign

---

it should be work

Comment: All that was needed was List Disk, Select Disk then Clean none of the rest was needed at all.

Comment: I gave you universal steps. This step's will resolve many problem with hard drive. Some times hard drive isn't visible in install creator window 's or something like that ,so for example this steps will fix it. Really, well know all this commends. :)